# In npm-cache directory, what are the folders other than _cacache for?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts, npm-cache

Navigating to npm cache directory, `Users/UserName/%AppData%/Roaming/npm-cache` in windows for example, I see so many folders. What are they for? When were they created and how can I remove them by npm cli? (I know the `_cacache` folder is for local cache of npm, so what stuff do other folders serve?)

Answer (score 5):

`npm-cache` is part of the cli

npm stores cache data in an opaque directory within the configured cache, named `_cacache`

You would need to delete any npm cache manually (packages etc)

`npm cache clean [<path>]`

npm will not remove data by itself: the cache will grow as new packages are installed.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/cache.html